# Condition for width of div content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want add CSS for class is `post-thumnail79` based on width of ID is `theID`. I make a condition like script below.

```
<script>
var widthrc = $("#theID").width();
  if(widthrc <= 328){
        $(".post-thumnail79").css("width","100%");
        alert(widthrc);
  }
  else{$(".post-thumnail79").css("width","50%");}
</script>
```

Although the condition is right, It still does not run. Check for. Thanks.

Comment: please provide jsfiddle

Comment: Try putting `alert(widthrc);` immediately after declaring the variable (outside of the if statement). See if the alerted value is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Sorry all. It actual my mistake. I will close this question and make another. However thank for your attempt to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax for .css is this:

```
.css({ 'property':'value', 'property':'value' })
```

Change your code like this:

```
var widthrc = $("#theID").width();
  if(widthrc <= 328){
        $(".post-thumnail79").css({"width","100%"});
        alert(widthrc);
}else{
  $(".post-thumnail79").css({ "width","50%"} );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I get your code working here:
https://gist.github.com/lslucas/e526fc7a8bb35157c803

There are more simple details like using $(function() and importing jquery lib.